# Randomly Generating Horse Racing Place Odds

Tags: probability, gambling

Suppose there is a horse race.

There are 3 horses (A, B and C), and 2 places (i.e. the place bets win if the horse comes 1st or 2nd)

The probabilities of the horses placing (i.e. coming 1st or 2nd) are 80%, 70% and 50%. Note that these probabilities add up to 200%, not 100%, as 2 horses win.

i.e.

There is an 80% chance of horse A coming 1st or 2nd.

There is a 70% chance of horse B coming 1st or 2nd.

There is a 50% chance of horse C coming 1st or 2nd.

How can I randomly select the 2 horses that place, given the probabilities above?

I would like to generalize the result for any number of runners or places. And ideally write a Python function to let me sample the data.

Comment: Those numbers need further explanation.  Could you edit this post to explain, for example, just what the value "0.8" refers to?  Which horse and which place?  And then could you show us how they would be used to compute, say, the chances that horses 1 and 3 are the first two horses?

Comment: I have changed the numbers to percentages. "Place" refers to 1st or 2nd. it doesn't matter which.

Comment: Understood.  But if you cannot show us how to compute the chances of any particular pair of horses placing, then you simply don't have enough information to simulate the situation.

Comment: My question was about how to compute the chances of any particular pair of horses placing. Once I know how to do that I can write a Python function to do it for me.

Comment: The information in the question should now be enough to compute the probabilities, but I don't know how to do so efficiently.

Comment: That's correct for three horses, but it no longer holds for more than three horses: you just don't have enough information in such cases.  Thus, your generalization is impossible.